# POSTing ByteArray Data from AS3 to PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, arrays

I have this:

```
import JPGEncoder;
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true, 0);
var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
bm.alpha = .5;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, screenCap);

function screenCap(e:Event):void {
bmd.draw(this);
var jpgVersion:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder( 80 );
var jpgStream:ByteArray  = jpgVersion.encode( bmd );
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/takeshot.php");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = jpgStream;
loader.load(request);
function dataOnLoad(e:Event){
 trace("Complete..");
}
}
```

Which takes a screenshot of the stage and is supposed to send the Byte array of the screenshot to PHP through POST data, My PHP just opens a new file, writes post data and closes (for testing purpose). But the $_POST is empty!

Comment: Could you post your php script (at least the part where you are accessing the POST data)?

Comment: I managed to fix this error by using $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] instead of $_POST; BUT now i have another error, the JPG file it generates is just black nothing else!

Comment: thats what I thought was wrong, using $_POST instead of reading out the raw post body. Thats why I asked for the PHP script. ;-)

Comment: Thanks but what about the new problem? Black screen instead of outputting whats ment to be generated?

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is an array with field -> value pairs. What you send is raw post data. You can retrieve it with `file_get_contents('php://input')` or from `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, but the former is the recommended method.

Comment: Hey, Thanks! But now the PHP file creates a JPG file but the JPG is plain black for some reason, what Flash is sending though is a screen with a gray rectangle!

Comment: Try to compute a checksum on each side to see if you get in PHP exactly what you send.

Comment: Try to check the headers http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php . Maybe the request is compressed.

Comment: The headers i am recieving: x-flash-version: 10,0,22,91
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 6650
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Host: localhost
Cache-Control: no-cache

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not in the AS? You should start with checking that the encoded jpeg is good before it's sent.

Comment: hmm i think it is the AS.. but any idea what i am ment to be checking for?

Comment: Try setting it as a source for an image. See if that renders OK.

Comment: Actually, i just checked the AS3 code and found it was the "true" parameter in BitmapData Method which should have been false! Thanks!